# How to find and plot correlated variables in R?

Tags: r, correlation, covariance

I'm reviewing factors related to cancer and hoping to find how they're related to one another. After I input my .xslx file into R, I'm at a loss how to use that list of data to find the z-scores for each measurement and then using that matrix Z of z-scores of X to compute the covariance matrix of A using cov(Z). How do I plot and analyze entries of A (which tell me how correlated the measurements in X are)?

This is an example of the plot I'm trying to achieve with my factors (UrbanPop, Rape, Assault, and Murder are factors of that plot -- you can ignore the states plotted).
[image]

Thank you!

The factors I'm reviewing are Age, BMI, Glucose, Insulin, HOMA, Leptin, Adiponectin, Resistin, MCP.1

This is my data -- I used dput(mydata)

structure(list(Age = c(48, 83, 82, 68, 86, 49, 89, 76, 73, 75, 
34, 29, 25, 24, 38, 44, 47, 61, 64, 32, 36, 34, 29, 35, 54, 45, 
50, 66, 35, 36, 66, 53, 28, 43, 51, 67, 66, 69, 60, 77, 76, 76, 
75, 69, 71, 66, 75, 78, 69, 85, 76, 77, 45, 45, 49, 34, 42, 68, 
51, 62, 38, 69, 49, 51, 59, 45, 54, 64, 46, 44, 45, 44, 51, 72, 
46, 43, 55, 43, 86, 41, 59, 81, 48, 71, 42, 65, 48, 85, 48, 58, 
40, 82, 52, 49, 60, 49, 44, 40, 71, 69, 74, 66, 65, 72, 57, 73, 
45, 46, 68, 75, 54, 45, 62, 65, 72, 86), BMI = c(23.5, 20.69049, 
23.12467, 21.36752, 21.11111, 22.85446, 22.7, 23.8, 22, 23, 21.47, 
23.01, 22.86, 18.67, 23.34, 20.76, 22.03, 32.03896, 34.52972, 
36.51264, 28.57668, 31.97501, 32.27079, 30.27682, 30.48316, 37.03561, 
38.57876, 31.44654, 35.25076, 34.17489, 36.21228, 36.79017, 35.85581, 
34.42217, 27.68878, 29.60677, 31.23859, 35.0927, 26.34929, 35.58793, 
29.21841, 27.2, 27.3, 32.5, 30.3, 27.7, 25.7, 25.3, 29.4, 26.6, 
27.1, 25.9, 21.30395, 20.83, 20.95661, 24.24242, 21.35991, 21.08281, 
19.13265, 22.65625, 22.49964, 21.51386, 21.36752, 22.89282, 22.83288, 
23.1405, 24.21875, 22.22222, 20.83, 19.56, 20.26, 24.74, 18.37, 
23.62, 22.21, 26.5625, 31.97501, 31.25, 26.66667, 26.67276, 28.67263, 
31.64037, 32.46191, 25.5102, 29.29688, 29.66655, 28.125, 27.68878, 
31.25, 29.15452, 30.83653, 31.21748, 30.80125, 32.46191, 31.23141, 
29.77778, 27.88762, 27.63605, 27.91552, 28.44444, 28.65014, 26.5625, 
30.91558, 29.13632, 34.83815, 37.10938, 29.38476, 33.18, 35.56, 
30.48, 36.05, 26.85, 26.84, 32.05, 25.59, 27.18), Glucose = c(70, 
92, 91, 77, 92, 92, 77, 118, 97, 83, 78, 82, 82, 88, 75, 86, 
84, 85, 95, 87, 86, 87, 84, 84, 90, 83, 106, 90, 90, 80, 101, 
101, 87, 89, 77, 79, 82, 101, 103, 76, 83, 94, 85, 93, 102, 90, 
94, 60, 89, 96, 110, 85, 102, 74, 94, 92, 93, 102, 93, 92, 95, 
112, 78, 103, 98, 116, 86, 98, 88, 114, 92, 106, 105, 105, 86, 
101, 92, 103, 201, 97, 77, 100, 99, 112, 98, 85, 90, 196, 199, 
139, 128, 100, 87, 134, 131, 70, 99, 103, 104, 108, 88, 89, 97, 
83, 95, 134, 90, 92, 131, 152, 119, 92, 100, 97, 82, 138), Insulin = c(2.707, 
3.115, 4.498, 3.226, 3.549, 3.226, 4.69, 6.47, 3.35, 4.952, 3.469, 
5.663, 4.09, 6.107, 5.782, 7.553, 2.869, 18.077, 4.427, 14.026, 
4.345, 4.53, 5.81, 4.376, 5.537, 6.76, 6.703, 9.245, 6.817, 6.59, 
15.533, 10.175, 8.576, 23.194, 3.855, 5.819, 4.181, 5.646, 5.138, 
3.881, 5.376, 14.07, 5.197, 5.43, 8.34, 6.042, 8.079, 3.508, 
10.704, 4.462, 26.211, 4.58, 13.852, 4.56, 12.305, 21.699, 2.999, 
6.2, 4.364, 3.482, 5.261, 6.683, 2.64, 2.74, 6.862, 4.902, 3.73, 
5.7, 3.42, 15.89, 3.44, 58.46, 6.03, 4.42, 36.94, 10.555, 16.635, 
4.328, 41.611, 22.033, 3.188, 9.669, 28.677, 10.395, 4.172, 14.649, 
2.54, 51.814, 12.162, 16.582, 41.894, 18.077, 30.212, 24.887, 
30.13, 8.396, 9.208, 2.432, 18.2, 8.808, 3.012, 6.524, 10.491, 
10.949, 12.548, 5.636, 4.713, 5.75, 8.15, 7.01, 11.91, 3.33, 
4.53, 5.73, 2.82, 19.91), HOMA = c(0.467409, 0.706897, 1.009651, 
0.612725, 0.805386, 0.732087, 0.890787, 1.883201, 0.801543, 1.013839, 
0.667436, 1.145436, 0.827271, 1.33, 1.06967, 1.6, 0.59, 3.790144, 
1.037394, 3.00998, 0.921719, 0.972138, 1.203832, 0.906707, 1.229214, 
1.383997, 1.752611, 2.05239, 1.513374, 1.300427, 3.869788, 2.534932, 
1.84041, 5.091856, 0.732193, 1.133929, 0.845677, 1.406607, 1.305395, 
0.727558, 1.100646, 3.262364, 1.089638, 1.245642, 2.098344, 1.341324, 
1.873251, 0.519184, 2.349885, 1.056602, 7.111918, 0.960273, 3.485163, 
0.832352, 2.853119, 4.924226, 0.687971, 1.55992, 1.001102, 0.790182, 
1.232828, 1.84629, 0.507936, 0.696143, 1.658774, 1.402626, 0.791257, 
1.37788, 0.742368, 4.468268, 0.780651, 15.28534, 1.56177, 1.14478, 
7.836205, 2.629602, 3.775036, 1.099601, 20.63073, 5.271762, 0.605507, 
2.38502, 7.002923, 2.871792, 1.008511, 3.071407, 0.56388, 25.05034, 
5.96992, 5.685415, 13.22733, 4.458993, 6.483495, 8.225983, 9.736007, 
1.449709, 2.248594, 0.61789, 4.668907, 2.346451, 0.653805, 1.432235, 
2.510147, 2.241625, 2.940415, 1.862886, 1.046286, 1.304867, 2.633537, 
2.628283, 3.495982, 0.755688, 1.1174, 1.370998, 0.570392, 6.777364
), Leptin = c(8.8071, 8.8438, 17.9393, 9.8827, 6.6994, 6.8317, 
6.964, 4.311, 4.47, 17.127, 14.57, 35.59, 20.45, 8.88, 15.26, 
14.09, 26.65, 30.7729, 21.2117, 49.3727, 15.1248, 28.7502, 45.6196, 
39.2134, 12.331, 39.9802, 46.6401, 45.9624, 50.6094, 10.2809, 
74.7069, 27.1841, 68.5102, 31.2128, 20.092, 21.9033, 16.2247, 
83.4821, 24.2998, 21.7863, 28.562, 35.891, 10.39, 15.145, 56.502, 
24.846, 65.926, 6.633, 45.272, 7.85, 21.778, 13.74, 7.6476, 7.7529, 
11.2406, 16.7353, 19.0826, 9.6994, 11.0816, 9.8648, 8.438, 32.58, 
6.3339, 8.0163, 14.9037, 17.9973, 8.6874, 12.1905, 12.87, 13.08, 
7.65, 18.16, 9.62, 21.78, 10.16, 9.8, 37.2234, 25.7816, 47.647, 
44.7059, 17.022, 38.8066, 46.076, 19.0653, 12.2617, 26.5166, 
15.5325, 70.8824, 18.1314, 22.8884, 31.0385, 31.6453, 29.2739, 
42.3914, 37.843, 51.3387, 12.6757, 14.3224, 53.4997, 14.7485, 
31.1233, 14.9084, 44.0217, 26.8081, 33.1612, 41.4064, 23.8479, 
18.69, 17.87, 50.53, 89.27, 54.68, 12.45, 61.48, 24.96, 90.28
), Adiponectin = c(9.7024, 5.429285, 22.43204, 7.16956, 4.81924, 
13.67975, 5.589865, 13.25132, 10.35873, 11.57899, 13.11, 26.72, 
23.67, 36.06, 17.95, 20.32, 38.04, 7.780255, 5.46262, 5.1, 8.6, 
7.64276, 6.209635, 9.048185, 9.73138, 4.617125, 4.667645, 10.35526, 
6.966895, 5.065915, 7.53955, 20.03, 4.7942, 8.300955, 3.19209, 
2.19428, 4.267105, 6.796985, 2.19428, 8.12555, 7.36996, 9.34663, 
9.000805, 11.78796, 8.13, 7.652055, 3.74122, 10.5673, 8.2863, 
7.9317, 4.935635, 9.75326, 21.05663, 8.237405, 8.412175, 21.82375, 
8.462915, 8.574655, 5.80762, 11.23624, 4.77192, 4.138025, 3.886145, 
9.349775, 4.230105, 4.294705, 3.70523, 4.783985, 18.55, 20.37, 
16.67, 16.1, 12.76, 17.86, 9.76, 6.420295, 11.01846, 12.71896, 
5.357135, 13.49487, 16.44048, 10.63653, 21.57, 5.4861, 6.695585, 
7.28287, 10.22231, 7.901685, 4.104105, 10.26266, 6.160995, 9.92365, 
6.26854, 10.79394, 8.40443, 10.73174, 5.47817, 6.78387, 1.65602, 
5.288025, 7.65222, 8.42996, 3.71009, 2.78491, 2.36495, 3.335665, 
6.644245, 9.16, 11.9, 10.06, 8.01, 12.1, 21.42, 22.54, 33.75, 
14.11), Resistin = c(7.99585, 4.06405, 9.27715, 12.766, 10.57635, 
10.3176, 12.9361, 5.1042, 6.28445, 7.0913, 6.92, 4.58, 5.14, 
6.85, 9.35, 7.64, 3.32, 13.68392, 6.70188, 17.10223, 9.1539, 
5.62592, 24.6033, 16.43706, 10.19299, 8.70448, 11.78388, 23.3819, 
22.03703, 15.72187, 22.32024, 10.26309, 21.44366, 6.71026, 10.37518, 
4.2075, 3.29175, 82.1, 20.2535, 17.2615, 8.04375, 8.4156, 7.5767, 
11.78796, 4.2989, 6.7052, 4.49685, 4.6638, 4.53, 9.6135, 8.49395, 
11.774, 23.03408, 28.0323, 23.1177, 12.06534, 17.37615, 13.74244, 
5.57055, 10.69548, 15.73606, 15.69876, 22.94254, 11.55492, 8.2049, 
5.2633, 10.34455, 13.91245, 13.56, 4.62, 7.84, 5.31, 3.21, 4.82, 
5.68, 16.1, 7.16514, 38.6531, 24.3701, 27.8325, 31.6904, 29.5583, 
10.15726, 42.7447, 53.6717, 19.46324, 16.11032, 55.2153, 53.6308, 
13.97399, 17.55503, 19.94687, 24.24591, 5.768, 11.50005, 20.76801, 
23.03306, 26.0136, 49.24184, 16.48508, 18.35574, 14.91922, 20.4685, 
14.76966, 9.9542, 6.89235, 15.55625, 8.89, 4.19, 11.73, 5.06, 
10.96, 7.32, 10.33, 3.27, 4.35), MCP.1 = c(417.114, 468.786, 
554.697, 928.22, 773.92, 530.41, 1256.083, 280.694, 136.855, 
318.302, 354.6, 174.8, 313.73, 632.22, 165.02, 63.61, 191.72, 
444.395, 252.449, 588.46, 534.224, 572.783, 904.981, 733.797, 
1227.91, 586.173, 887.16, 1102.11, 667.928, 581.313, 864.968, 
695.754, 358.624, 960.246, 473.859, 585.307, 634.602, 263.499, 
378.996, 618.272, 698.789, 377.227, 335.393, 270.142, 200.976, 
225.88, 206.802, 209.749, 215.769, 232.006, 45.843, 488.829, 
552.444, 382.955, 573.63, 481.949, 321.919, 448.799, 90.6, 703.973, 
199.055, 713.239, 737.672, 359.232, 355.31, 518.586, 635.049, 
395.976, 301.21, 220.66, 193.87, 244.75, 513.66, 195.94, 312, 
806.724, 483.377, 775.322, 1698.44, 783.796, 910.489, 426.175, 
738.034, 799.898, 1041.843, 1698.44, 1698.44, 1078.359, 1698.44, 
923.886, 638.261, 994.316, 764.667, 656.393, 396.021, 602.486, 
407.206, 293.123, 256.001, 353.568, 572.401, 269.487, 396.648, 
232.018, 655.834, 788.902, 621.273, 209.19, 198.4, 99.45, 218.28, 
268.23, 330.16, 314.05, 392.46, 90.09)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-116L))

Comment: How many columns of data does the csv has? You have to describe your dataset somehow.

Comment: Oh sorry! The data has 9 columns and 116 rows (all numbers)

Comment: you can share your data so someone can copy them paste them and work directly on them. say that mtcars is a standard dataset in r if you type mtcars you will see an output in the console. if then you run dput(mtcars) you will get a sharable output if you copy and paste this output here people may be able to help you

Comment: My data is quite large, how can I share my data here? I tried to copy and paste from R but it turns out messy.

Comment: I tried following online advice to share my data using dput(mydata) and then copy and pasting. Let me know if I should try another method to make it easier for you guys!

Answer (score 0):

To get the z-scores you can use `scale()` and to get the covariance matrix you can use `cov()`. But, there is no reason to produce the covariance matrix from the z-scores instead of the raw data. You can also visualize a correlation matrix using the `corrplot` function in the `corrplot` package. The `corrplot` function will also take the raw data as an input. Not the covariance matrix.

Comment: I tried to download the corrplot package but when I type in corrplot(mydata), it says -- Error in corrplot(mydata) : could not find function "corrplot".
Also, using scale() gives me two additional values at the end. Are those the covariance and correlation?

Comment: Also, will using corrplot give me vectors of all the factors (so I can determine how correlated they are to another by determining the vector angles)? I want to plot the factor vectors on one plot to do so! I added a plot example of what I'm trying to achieve in my post (urbanpop, murder, rape, assault are the factors of that plot).

Comment: not sure why you are getting these errors. did you run `install.packages("corrplot"); library(corrplot)` before running the function? as for `scale()`, that shouldn't be the case. perhaps if you have non-numeric data it will produce unexpected results. You should be calling `scale` on numeric data. as for the vectors of correlations. No, that which you describe is obtained using `cor()` or `cov()`

Comment: Oh, I got it to work using the code you provided. Thank you for that! But how can I plot those vectors onto a single plot? I tried corrplot function but doesn't seem like what I'm trying to produce. Sorry if I'm not explaining clear enough.

Comment: @Ang it sounds like you're looking for a biplot: `model <- vegan::rda(data, scale = TRUE); stats:biplot(model, scaling = "symmetric")`